# Creating both sales header and sales lines in one call i NAV OData REST API

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

### What we want to do

We want to create both a `sales header` and the corresponding `sales lines` in one API call.

### How we're trying to do it

To do this we're trying to do a **deep insert** as specified in the [OData spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.01-cs01.html#_Toc499720609).

Example

```
POST http://our-nav-host:12202/NAV110_TEST/ODataV4/Company('CompanyName')/SalesOrder
{
    "No": "1234",
    "Sell_to_Customer_No": "1234",
    "Sell_to_Customer_Name": "Test",
    "Sell_to_Address": "Teststreet 56",
    "Sell_to_Address_2": "",
    "Sell_to_Post_Code": "1234",
    "Sell_to_City": "Test",
    "SalesOrderSalesLines": [
        {
            "Document_Type": "Order",
            "Document_No": "1234",
            "Line_No": 10000,
            "Type": "Item",
            "No": "21981"
        }
    ]
}
```

We get a `200 OK` and the `sales header` is created but without any `sales lines`.

### NAV Config

We have published a web service for **page 42** (Sales Order) and we're using the corresponding **OData V4 URL** in the call.

### SOAP

If we try to do the same with the SOAP URL and a SOAP-call it works. The sales order is created with the sales lines. But we would very much like to NOT use SOAP.

Comment: Using the NAV interface the user cannot make both a sales header and lines in 'one call'...  I would recommend to create a Sales Header first, then create multiple Sales Lines.  [Example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2009/11/17/extending-page-web-services-and-creating-a-sales-order-again/)

Comment: Thank you @ian_scho for commenting. I can create both sales header and sales lines in one call using SOAP to the same page (42). I've stumbled upon the link you provided in my search but I think that info isn't applicable to NAV 2018. Since it works via SOAP.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JoeyCarlisle no unfortunately not. We ended up using SOAP (yuck) instead. We've "heard" that this works in BC but we haven't upgraded and tested.